# Deep copy of a np.array of np.array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array of different numpy arrays and I want to make a deep copy of the arrays. I found out the following:

```
import numpy as np

pairs = [(2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5)]
array_of_arrays = np.array([np.arange(a*b).reshape(a,b) for (a, b) in pairs])

a = array_of_arrays[:] # Does not work
b = array_of_arrays[:][:] # Does not work
c = np.array(array_of_arrays, copy=True) # Does not work
d = np.array([np.array(x, copy=True) for x in array_of_arrays])

array_of_arrays[0][0,0] = 100
print a[0][0,0], b[0][0,0], c[0][0,0], d[0][0,0]
```

Is d the best way to do this? Is there a deep copy function I missed?
And what is the best way to interact with each element in this array of different sized arrays?

Comment: You really should expand on the 'does not work' lines.

Comment: I tested using np.copy (which should be the same as adding copy=True) and the problem is that it is actually a copy by reference! (So a change in the original reflected in the copy, for some reason). np.copy or copy=True works well for normal arrays, though.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import copy

pairs = [(2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5)]
array_of_arrays = np.array([np.arange(a*b).reshape(a,b) for (a, b) in pairs])

a = copy.deepcopy(array_of_arrays)
```

Feel free to read up more about this [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html).

Oh, here is simplest test case:

```
a[0][0,0]
print a[0][0,0], array_of_arrays[0][0,0]
```

Comment: Nice test case!

Comment: >>> np.array([np.arange(a*b).reshape(a,b) for (a, b) in pairs])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 1 dimensions. The detected shape was (3,) + inhomogeneous part.

(Python 3.8.10, Numpy 1.24.2.) But this works as expected:
>>> ([np.arange(a*b).reshape(a,b) for (a, b) in pairs])

Comment: "a[0][0,0]": shouldn't this read "a[0][0,0] = 99" or "array_of_arrays[0][0,0] = 100" the like?
Otherwise the following are identical:
print a[0][0,0], array_of_arrays[0][0,0]

Answer (score 6):

Just use `np.array(old_array)` should work for the latest version of numpy

```
array_to_be_copy = np.zeros([3, 3])
deep_copied_array = np.array(array_to_be_copy)
```

My numpy version: 1.21.1

Answer (score 5):

```
In [276]: array_of_arrays
Out[276]: 
array([array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5]]),
       array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]]),
       array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]])], dtype=object)
```

`array_of_arrays` is `dtype=object`; that means each element of the array is a pointer to an object else where in memory.  In this case those elements are arrays of different sizes.

```
a = array_of_arrays[:]
```

`a` is a new array, but a view of `array_of_arrays`; that is, it has the same data buffer (which in this case is list of pointers).

```
b = array_of_arrays[:][:]
```

this is just a view of a view.  The second `[:]` acts on the result of the first.

```
c = np.array(array_of_arrays, copy=True)
```

This is the same as `array_of_arrays.copy()`. `c` has a new data buffer, a copy of the originals

If I replace an element of `c`, it will not affect `array_of_arrays`:

```
c[0] = np.arange(3)
```

But if I modify an element of `c`, it will modify the same element in `array_of_arrays` - because they both point to the same array.

The same sort of thing applies to nested lists of lists.  What `array` adds is the `view` case.

```
d = np.array([np.array(x, copy=True) for x in array_of_arrays])
```

In this case you are making copies of the individual elements.  As others noted there is a `deepcopy` function.  It was designed for things like lists of lists, but works on arrays as well.  It is basically doing what you do with `d`; recursively working down the nesting tree.

In general, an object array is like list nesting.  A few operations cross the object boundary, e.g.

```
 array_of_arrays+1
```

but even this effectively is

```
np.array([x+1 for x in array_of_arrays])
```

One thing that a object array adds, compared to a list, is operations like `reshape`.  `array_of_arrays.reshape(3,1)` makes it 2d;  if it had 4 elements you could do `array_of_arrays.reshape(2,2)`.  Some times that's handy; other times it's a pain (it's harder to iterate).

Answer (score 4):

Beaten by one minute. Indeed, deepcopy is the answer here.

To your second question abut indexing: I have a feeling that you may be better off with a simple list or a dictionary-type data structure here. np.arrays make sense primarily if each array element is of the same type. Of course you can argue that each element in array_of_arrays is another array, but what is the benefit of having them collected in a numpy array instead of a simple list?

```
list_of_arrays = [np.arange(a*b).reshape(a,b) for (a, b) in pairs]
```

Answer (score 0):

When to warn of possible depreciation:

1. ..\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:23: DeprecationWarning: elementwise comparison failed; this will raise an error in the future.

I decided like that:

```
    import numpy as np
    import copy
    
    def deepCopyArrayNumPy(arrayNunpy):
        clone = copy.deepcopy(arrayNunpy.tolist())
        return np.array(clone)
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, but can you explain why it is better than the accepted answer using deepcopy directly?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can make a deep copy of a NumPy array using the numpy.copy() function. You can find the documentation for this function [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.copy.html).

The documentation provides an example of how to use the function:

```
import numpy as np

# Create an array x, with a reference y and a copy z:
x = np.array([1, 2, 3])
y = x
z = np.copy(x)

# Modify x and check if y and z are affected:
x[0] = 10
print(x[0] == y[0])  # True
print(x[0] == z[0])  # False
```

You can also copy an array using the following methods:

```
x = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]], order='F')
y = x.copy()
x.fill(0)
print(x == y) # [[False False False]
              #  [False False False]]
```

You can find the documentation for this method [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.copy.html).

Answer (score -1):

A simple np.asarray() would do it

```
np.asarray(array_of_arrays)
```

For reference: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.asarray.html

Comment: It will  not do a deep copy.
Python 3.7.4 (default, Aug 13 2019, 20:35:49) 
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.zeros((3,3))
>>> a
array([[0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.]])
>>> b = np.asarray(a)
>>> b
array([[0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.]])
>>> a[0,0] = 1
>>> a
array([[1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.]])
>>> b
array([[1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.]])
>>>