# Numpy: Set array element to another array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to set an element of a Numpy array to be another Numpy array. I'm not sure on how to do this since every time I try I get `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`

I know this is possible with Python's `list` since I can append the new array to list and it will work.

This is an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
import numpy as np

finalArray = np.zeros(3)
finalList = []

a = np.arange(128).reshape(32,4)
b = np.arange(124).reshape(31,4)
c = np.arange(120).reshape(30,4)

# This works
finalList.append(a)
finalList.append(b)
finalList.append(c)

# This doesn't work
finalArray[0] = a
finalArray[1] = b
finalArray[2] = c
```

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: "I'm trying to set an element of a Numpy array to be another Numpy array" - bad move. NumPy might not be a good fit for your program's needs.

Comment: What do you want the shape/dtypes of finalList to be?

Comment: I was attempting to have variable shapes. For instance in the description above, `a`, `b`, and `c` have different shapes and I was hoping to have a numpy array filled with those.

Answer (score 1):

It would work if

```
finalArray = np.zeros(3, dtype=object)
finalArray[0] = a
```

Then `finalArray` takes object points like a list.

But I hesitate suggesting this because this feature is being abused or misused by beginners.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37597524/901925 - my answer to another question about a deep copy of an array of arrays.

The `concatenate` answer is the only alternative that makes sense, given the dimensions of your arrays.

A variation on the `concatenate` is

```
finalArray = np.zeros((93,4),a.dtype)
finalArray[:32,:] = a
etc
```

In other words, make `finalArray` big enough to receive the elements of the arrays, and copy values.

Answer (score 0):

Numpy arrays are closer to statically typed. They can only contain the types specified on creation. They are more like the arrays of C or Java.  While it may be possible to create a numpy array of numpy arrays (where each sub-array is treated as an generic python object), you most likely want to make a proper 2D numpy array.

To create a two dimensional array, feed a two dimensional list into the np.array function. For example,

```
finalArray = np.array([[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]])
```

creates a 3x3 two dimensional array filled with zeros.

Comment: You can also do this with `np.zeros((3, 3), np.int64)`. That said, I'm not sure how this solves the question (what is `x`?) Edit: to be fair nor does mine, the question is a little ill-defined!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for [`numpy.concatenate`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html):

```
In [11]: np.concatenate((a, b, c))
Out[11]:
array([[  0,   1,   2,   3],
       [  4,   5,   6,   7],
       [  8,   9,  10,  11],
       [ 12,  13,  14,  15],
       [ 16,  17,  18,  19],
       ...
```

This creates a single 93 x 4 numpy array:

```
In [12]: np.concatenate((a, b, c)).shape
Out[12]: (93, 4)
```