# Storing a 2-D array

Tags: python, numpy

I have written a code to create a 2-D array H inside a for-loop. Is there any way to store these values of H into another array with n elements so that I can call it later on in my program? I tried using `a[i] = H` but I get an error  `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`

```
import numpy as np

tmin = -30.
tmax = 80.
ntime = 400
Deltat = (tmax-tmin)/ntime

t = np.linspace(tmin,tmax,400)

omega0 = 3.5

tau_s_p = 15

tP = 10 
tS = 35

delta_P = 0.5
delta_S = -0.5


omega_P = np.zeros(len(t))
omega_S = np.zeros(len(t))
H_t = np.zeros(len(t))

for n in range(0,len(t)-1):
   
    omega_P[n] = omega0*np.exp((-(t[n]-tP)**2)/(tau_s_p**2))
    omega_S[n] = omega0*np.exp((-(t[n]-tS)**2)/(tau_s_p**2))
    H = np.array([[0, omega_P[n] , 0], [omega_P[n], 2*delta_P, omega_S[n]],[0,omega_S[n],2*(delta_P - delta_S)]])
```

Comment: You don't show the whole code.  What's `a`?

Comment: @hpaulj a is just an array I initialize to store the values of H for each iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to copy them element for element. With `a[i] = H` you try to store a whole array in an element.

Or you can use the `deepcopy` function from the `copy` module.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37593181

Comment: I tried element by element but that was too long so I was trying to make my code more compact. The ```deepcopy``` function works perfectly.