# variables changing after a function call in python

Tags: python, function, numpy

Ive been working on some code recently for a project in python and im confused by the output im getting from this code

```
def sigmoid(input_matrix):
    rows = input_matrix.shape[0]
    columns = input_matrix.shape[1]
    for i in range(0,rows):
        for j in range(0,columns):
            input_matrix[i,j] = (1 / (1 + math.exp(-(input_matrix[i,j]))))
    return input_matrix

def feed_forward(W_L_1 , A_L_0 , B_L_1):
    weighted_sum = np.add(np.dot(W_L_1,A_L_0), B_L_1)
    activation = sigmoid(weighted_sum)
    return [weighted_sum,activation]

a = np.zeros((1,1))
b = feed_forward(a,a,a)
print(b[0])
print(b[1])
```

when I print both b[0] and b[1] give values of .5 even though b[0] should equal 0. Also in addition to this when I place the '''weighted_sum = np.add(np.dot(W_L_1,A_L_0), B_L_1)''' again after the 'actvation' line it provides the correct result. Its as if the 'activation' line has changed the value of the weighted sum value.
Was wondering if anyone could spread some light on this I can work around this but am interested as to why this is happening. Thanks!!

Comment: your `sigmoid` function changes the array you pass to it. `input_matrix[i,j] =  ...` why did you expect it *not* to change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `sigmoid`, you're changing the value of the matrix passed as parameter, in this line:

```
input_matrix[i,j] = ...
```

If you want to prevent this from happening, create a copy of the matrix before calling `sigmoid`, and call it like this: `sigmoid(copy_of_weighted_sum)`.

Comment: Thanks for the idea I've gave this a try but still got the same result!

Comment: My recommendation _has_ to work. How did you copy the matrix?

Comment: ```def sigmoid(input_matrix):
    test = input_matrix
    rows = test.shape[0]
    columns = test.shape[1]
    for i in range(0,rows):
        for j in range(0,columns):
            test[i,j] = (1 / (1 + math.exp(-(input_matrix[i,j]))))
    return test``` sorry about the formatting

Comment: I was under the impression too and I could be very wrong about this that the scope of the variable was only within that function and wasnt passed down to an inner function ie:```def inner(a):
    a = 3


def outer():
    a = 4
    inner(a)
    print(a)

outer()```gives 4 as the result

Comment: Here's the problem, this line is not copying the matrix, at all! `test = input_matrix`. That's just creating another reference pointing to the exact, same object. You've been passing around and modifying a single matrix, and of course any change you do on it will be reflected on all the variables referencing it.

Comment: Take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37593013/deep-copy-of-a-np-array-of-np-array) to learn how to actually _copy_ a numpy matrix.